# What are the dimensions of the ladders on the West Coast Trail?

Tags: canada, backpacking

We're training for West Coast Trail, and I'm going to build a ladder to practice going up and down, and I'm curious if anyone knows what the dimensions of the ladder are so I can make an accurate replica. My plan is to use dimensional lumber, with 2x4's for rungs, I'm just wondering what the rung spacing is? I imagine it's somewhere between 12 and 16 inches. I'm also curious what the width of the ladders is. There are a lot of pictures online, so I can make a pretty good guess, but I'm wondering if anyone here has any anecdotal info I can use.

Comment: I wonder how hard it would to be to get in contact with a group who maintains a section with ladders to see if they have building specs for them

Comment: They're narrow-ish, sometimes.  To be honest, don't sweat it overmuch.  There is *one* section that is actually fairly high - 6m? 10m? - and *might* worry someone who is very worried about heights.  I am scared of heights and had no big issue there.  If you're really concerned I'd lower the backpack on a rope, maybe, so I can descend more "safely".  If you're instead concerned about heavy packs + ladders I'd look into lessening the backpack load instead which brings benefits throughout that hike.  Enjoy!

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica lol, I'm not worried about heights, I just want to make a replica ladder for exercise and I'm a stickler for the details: I want to make an accurate replica.

Comment: And I am saying they are not much of a factor in the overall WCT scheme of things.  Most of them are 1.5-2.5m high, and slanted 60-75°.  Glorified ladders to bunkbeds, really.  If you need verisimilitude, I'd concentrate on the "up rock, down mud into puddle, up root, while wearing full pack" aspects of that trail, esp 30 southmost km.  Without *apparent* altitude gain on a map.  That is its defining attribute, IMHO - we were doing max 2km/hr IIRC heading North, until first southern campground.  Gaiters, gaiters, gaiters.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I get what you're saying, but I'd still like to get an answer to the question.